# Drop-down list AutoPostBack is not firing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, combobox

In my asp.net website I have created a user control called **GlobalHeader.ascx**  to make header content consistent throughout the website and put a text box control for search functionality as given below:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <form id="sample"></form>
</div>
<div>
  <form id="cse-search-box" name="cse-search-box" method="get" action="/Search Results.aspx">
  <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11;NB:1" />
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="search-txt" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search';" value="Search"/>
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" class="search-iocn" />
</form>
```

Now in child page I'm having a drop-down control having **AutoPostBack=true** and **OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpdwnListSelectedIndexChanged"**  i.e. on item change event **DrpdwnListSelectedIndexChanged** is fired and and show some data just under drop-down list. BUT this functionality is **ONLY** work when I **remove search functionality** from Header user control.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpdwnList" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpdwnListSelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

This means **form** tag preventing drop-down list **AutoPostBack** functionality to work.
Why so?
How can I make both functionality work together?

Interesting thing is that If I remove `<form id="sample"></form>` from top search functionality doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a larger chunk of code? Feels like the problem is in a higher level.

Comment: actually this is the only code nothing else...